# Invalid parameter in encrypt (JavaScript, UWP)

Tags: javascript, uwp, cryptography

I would like to encrypt data in UWP appliaction writen in javascript.

```
var publicKey = Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.PersistedKeyProvider.openPublicKeyFromCertificate(cert, "", Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.CryptographicPadding.none);
var buffer = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.createFromByteArray(bytes);
var iv = null;
var encrypted = Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.CryptographicEngine.encrypt(publicKey, buffer, iv);
```

But I get exception on the last line:
0x80090027 - JavaScript runtime error: Parametr není správný.
(Invalid parameter)

But which parameter?

Certificate is created by command

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -Subject "test" -KeyAlgorithm RSA -KeyLength 2048 -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My"
```

and obtained by Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.CertificateStores.

Answer (score 0):

When RSA is used, buffer must have some defined size. If it is smaller exception (Invalid parameter - without any details) is raised.
When padding is changed from CryptographicPadding.none to CryptographicPadding.rsaPkcs1V15 encrypting works.